# VPNサーバ１台に対し、VPNルータのVPNクライアント機能で接続した場合、配下はお互いに通信できるのでしょうか。

Tags: network, vpn

A拠点にVPNサーバ（仮にRouterA/固定IP）があると仮定し、そこから別拠点BまたはCにあるVPNクライアント機能のあるルータ（仮にRouterB動的IP/RouterC動的IP）から接続した場合、RouterBまたはRouterCの配下にいるPCなどはお互いに通信（Ping）が可能なのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

拠点AをHUBにして、拠点BーC間を相互に接続させる構成は可能です。
これは 一般的には「ハブアンドスポーク」と呼ばれる構成（トポロジー）です。
反対に、すべての拠点間を接続する（A-B、A-C、C-B）のを「フルメッシュ」と呼びます。

Comment: 用語、勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

VPNに限らず、拠点間通信を認めるかどうかは組織のポリシーと設定次第です。認める、認めない、どちらも一般的です。

なお、ルータ同士のVPN接続の場合、「サーバ」「クライアント」という言い方はあまりしません。

Comment: >拠点間通信を認めるかどうかは組織のポリシーと設定次第
組織のポリシーとしての話はここでは無視していただいて結構なので、設定次第という事は可という事ですね。